# How do I move a vmware guest machine to another user?

Tags: permissions, partition, vmware, uuid

I have 2 users in my computer running Arch Linux. I recently moved a virtual installation of windows 7 from one user to another. I changed the owner of the moved folder to the new user recursively.

I am able to open the virtual machine when I open from root user, however I am not able to open it from the new user.

Should I make some permission changes? No error is popping up. How can I find out what's happening?

How to properly migrate a virtual machine to a new user?

---

I think I found out what is happening. The problem is with the raw partition I added to the virtual machine, for the creation of which I used the root user (the VMplayer does not allow a normal user to add a raw partition).

On removing the raw partition hard disk, I was able to boot the machine without root.

I found [a page](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001976) where they describe what to do to circumvent this. However, I have two hard drives which get randomly mounted by udev as sda and sdb.

How can I make a node as described in the linked page using UUID? Will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is due to the drives moving around putting something like

```
UUID="0ECA6DA1246D89E4" /media/scratch  ntfs    auto,rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
```

in /etc/fstab should do the trick.  *Before you edit it, make a backup*

Just create /media/scratch (or whatever you want to call it - it needs to match what's in the file including the case) with mkdir.  To find the UUID, use blkid.

This example is on a dual boot machine to make the Windows D: visible in linux.